# Why does the textfields and button disappears after clicking the Go button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have my code(html/javascript) here which allows user to input the size and color of the square.The problem is when i click the go button the textfields disappear including the button and the one that displays is the output.Is there any ways that i could retain the textfields and the button then output the square below it?

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
size=0;
function display(form){
    size=form.inputbox.value;
    color=form.inputbox2.value;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(i==0||i==(size-1)){
                        document.write("<font color="+color+">*&nbsp;");
                    }
                else if (j == 0||j == (size-1)) {
                        document.write("*&nbsp;");
                    }
                else {
                        document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                    }
            }
                    document.write("<br>");
        }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" action="" method="get">
    Input size of the square:
        <input type="text" name="inputbox" value=""><br>
    Input color of the square:
        <input type="text" name="inputbox2" value="">

    <input type="button" name="button" value="Go" onClick="display(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a quick note in case you're unaware: `<font>` has been deprecated for a long time.

Comment: because you'r using `document.write`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `document.write` on a page that has completed rendering will destroy the exiting DOM document on the page, replacing it with only the newly written HTML elements.

If you wish to add to existing DOM elements, select an element and write to its `innerHTML` property instead.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
size=0;
function display(form){
    size=form.inputbox.value;
    color=form.inputbox2.value;

    // A node to write into
    writeTo = document.getElementById('writeTo');

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(i==0||i==(size-1)){
                        writeTo.innerHTML = writeTo.innerHTML + "<font color="+color+">*&nbsp;";
                    }
                else if (j == 0||j == (size-1)) {
                        writeTo.innerHTML = writeTo.innerHTML + "*&nbsp;";
                    }
                else {
                        writeTo.innerHTML = writeTo.innerHTML + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
            }
                    writeTo.innerHTML = writeTo.innerHTML + "<br>";
        }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" action="" method="get">
    Input size of the square:
        <input type="text" name="inputbox" value=""><br>
    Input color of the square:
        <input type="text" name="inputbox2" value="">

    <input type="button" name="button" value="Go" onClick="display(this.form)">
    </form>
    <div id='writeTo'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And add an empty node to your HTML something like:

```
<div id='writeTo'></div>
```

[Here it is in action on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/rQddg/)

To get the square to be all the correct color, it is easiest to change the CSS color property of `<div id='writeTo'>`

```
document.getElementById('writeTo').style.color = color;
```

Comment: it only prints 1 asterisk now.it does not form a square anymore,but it already writes below the textfield.

Comment: @claire0us I see what you're trying to do.  See my change above and check out the link to jsFiddle. It works now, except that the font color only applies to the top and bottom lines. That is more easily solved by changing the CSS color property of the containing ` <div>` though.